# Is it possible to adjust AppFabric Cache server to store larger objects?

Tags: .net, caching, .net-4.0, appfabric

I'm getting an error with the AppFabric Cache Server when I presume a larger object graph gets added to the cache.

*ErrorCode :SubStatus:The connection was terminated, possibly due to server or network problems or serialized Object size is greater than MaxBufferSize on server.  Result of the request is unknown.*

I know for sure its not a network problem.  I was able to add a bunch of objects to cache before this particular one.  And looking into it, the object is a bit bigger than the others that got added to cache.

**How can I adjust the MaxBufferSize on AppFabric Cache?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Client Side it is the [maxBufferSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.applicationserver.caching.datacachetransportproperties.maxbuffersize.aspx) on the transport element in your DataCacheClient config section.

```
   <transportProperties  ..whatever else you have..  maxBufferSize="8388608"  />
```

Edit:

Example of the DataCacheClient section from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee790816.aspx)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<!--configSections must be the FIRST element -->
<configSections>
<!-- required to read the <dataCacheClient> element -->
<section name="dataCacheClient"
     type="Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCacheClientSection,
        Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, 
        Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
      allowLocation="true"
      allowDefinition="Everywhere"/>
</configSections>

<dataCacheClient requestTimeout="15000" channelOpenTimeout="3000" maxConnectionsToServer="1">
  <localCache isEnabled="true" sync="TimeoutBased" ttlValue="300" objectCount="10000"/>
  <clientNotification pollInterval="300" maxQueueLength="10000"/>
  <hosts>
     <host name="CacheServer1" cachePort="22233"/>
     <host name="CacheServer2" cachePort="22233"/>
  </hosts>
  <securityProperties mode="Transport" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" />
  <transportProperties connectionBufferSize="131072" maxBufferPoolSize="268435456" 
                       maxBufferSize="8388608" maxOutputDelay="2" channelInitializationTimeout="60000" 
                       receiveTimeout="600000"/>
  </dataCacheClient>
 </configuration>
```

Comment: Isn't there something that has to be done on the server side as well?

Comment: Could you provide a sample XML config of the DataCache section?

Comment: Server requires same settings, under advancedProperties element of its config.

Comment: In addition to this the adjustments made to the buffer sizes and receiveTimeout noted here (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/velocity/thread/975bb18e-3402-4251-bd10-dd084e5f308f?prof=required) solved my problem.


<transportProperties maxOutputDelay="2"
    channelInitializationTimeout="60000"
    receiveTimeout="900000"
    maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
    maxBufferSize="2147483647"/>

Answer (score 9):

You need to increase the buffer size on the server side as well:

If you use XML config add the following:

```
<advancedProperties>      
    <transportProperties maxBufferSize="8388608" />
</advancedProperties>
```

If you use SQL configuration,you need to export it to a file:

```
Export-CacheClusterConfig -File [yourfilepath]
```

Change the file as listed above and than import it again:

```
Stop-CacheCluster 
Import-CacheClusterConfig -File [yourfilepath]
Start-CacheCluster
```

Nevertheless it's not recommended to store large files in the AppFabric Cache.