# Appfabric max object size

Tags: windows, appfabric-cache

While caching some large objects (may be around 10mb) in Appfabric cache, it throws following exception

ErrorCode :SubStatus:The connection was terminated, possibly due to server or network problems or serialized Object size is greater than MaxBufferSize on server. Result of the request is unknown.

Here are the transport channel setting

<transportProperties connectionBufferSize="131072"  **maxBufferPoolSize="268435456"
                                maxBufferSize="50000000"**   maxOutputDelay="2" channelInitializationTimeout="60000"
                                 receiveTimeout="600000"/>

Even though the maxBufferPoolSize is set above 2GB, why would storing 10MB object throws exception. Please let me know if I am missing something here.

Answer (score 1):

The WCF transport settings need to be set on both the [client and server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3449683/is-it-possible-to-adjust-appfabric-cache-server-to-store-larger-objects) to take effect.

AFAIK the max possible setting for both `maxBufferSize` and `maxBufferPoolSize` is 2GB, but I wouldn't set these arbitrarily large, as it will [chew memory](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wcf/thread/d6e234d3-942f-4e9d-8470-32618d3f3212/).